# Class not found JettyHttpServerProvider -> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, jax-ws, com.sun.net.httpserver

By setting

```
 System.setProperty(.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider",
          "org.eclipse.jetty.jaxws2spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");
```

The **org.eclipse.jetty.jaxws2spi.JettyHttpServerProvider** class is not found.

```
sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.jaxws2spi.JettyHttpServerProvider
```

I have included libs: Jetty 9, jaxws-ri-2.2.10, Jaxb-2.2.7

I already checked out:
[Metro + Jetty + OSGi = pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876126/metro-jetty-osgi-pain)

but the codehaus stuff is afaik moved to eclipse...

Where is the **org.eclipse.jetty.jaxws2spi.JettyHttpServerProvider** ?

**Edit:**

Ok i found out that it was renamed to **org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider**

But now i am getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/spi/JettyHttpServerProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Solved:
By using Jetty 9.0.6 it is compatible with Java 7

Comment: Did you include JAX-WS RI?

Comment: jaxws-ri-2.2.10 is included

Comment: Don't use Jetty 9.0.6, the entire Jetty 9.0.x version is an transition suite from Servlet 3.0 to Servlet 3.1 (it even uses beta releases of the servlet 3.1 spec!).  Use at least Jetty 9.1.x or even better 9.2.x (which also support Java 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the Java Class File format byte offsets 6 and 7 are used to store the class file version. [The table here will help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

Version 52 is used to indicate that the class file format is Java 8. My guess is that you're using a library with a Java 8 requirement (or just one that was built using Java 8 and not targeting a previous class file format) and running on Java 7.

Jetty 9 is supposed to be [Java 1.7 based](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php) which means you're either using something newer or you're using somebody's customised version that requires Java 8.

Comment: 9.3.1 is Java 8, i downgraded to 9.0.6

Comment: Jetty 9.3.0 was the first Java 8 release, just after the Java 7 final EOL.  When Java 8 goes EOL the next major release of Jetty will drop support as well.  (Note: Jetty versioning is `{servlet_spec_support}.{major_version}.{minor_version}` meaning Jetty 9.3 is 3 major versions after 9.0)